# Can .save() Mongoose Schema only one time, next i need to restart node.js server to save it again

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have this problem. First i start Mongoose connecting it to Atlas Db.

dbConfig.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://myMongoDbOnAtlas?retryWrites=true&w=majority";', 
  { 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  }
);

mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected to db');
}).on('error', (error) => {
  console.warn('Error: ' + error);
})

module.exports = mongoose;
```

/db/schema/offices.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const OfficeSchema = new Schema({
  // Some Properties
});

const Office = mongoose.model('offices', OfficeSchema);

module.exports = Office;
```

addOfficeController.js

```
const Office = require('../db/schema/office');
const mongoose = require('../db/dbConfig');

const addOffice = async (req, res, next) => {

  const office = req.body;
  let newOffice = new Office(office);

  newOffice.save((err, data) => {
    if(err){
      res.status(400).send(err);
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      res.status(201).send(data);
    }

    mongoose.connection.close();

  })
};

module.exports = {
  addOffice
};
```

Now when i start the Node server my controller works fine and save on db the data, but if i try to do it again the callback is an error: MongooseError: Operation `offices.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Comment: Don't close the connection after updating. You only need to call `connection.close()` when you quit your server.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved in this way

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const startDb = () => {
  mongoose.connect('myMongoDb@cluster0.hazp8.mongodb.net/db?retryWrites=true";', 
  { 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  }
  );

  mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Connected to db');
  }).on('error', (error) => {
    console.warn('Error: ' + error);
  })
}

module.exports = startDb;
```

I exported a function that starts the connection to db, and after save() I close the connection.